# Can we solve this iterative equation?

Tags: recurrence-relations

As described by the title, can we obtain a formula for $X_k$?
$$X_k=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}X_{k-1-i}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{p^j}{1-p^j}\right)^{i+1},X_0=1.$$